# How to cross-reference answer to another question

Tags: discussion

The solution described in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/13980286/55358 also works for this question: [How to trace a value of UIWebView.scrollView.contentOffset](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12919704/55358), but I'm kinda hesitant to flag the 2nd question as a duplicate, since it does ask about something slightly different.

For now, I posted an answer to the 2nd question referencing the answer to the 1st, but I'd like to know if there is A Better Way for this kind of situation.

Comment: Just vote to close as a duplicate, if the solution is the same.

Comment: Otherwise use a comment to point out the other answer, or incorporate parts of the other answer (with attribution) in a new answer, provided there are other points to add to make it a full answer.

Comment: While answers can help validate that a question is duplicate, *the questions themselves must be duplicated to close as duplicate.*

Answer (score 1):

Treat the other answer the same way you would treat any other case of finding the needed information elsewhere on the web: link *and also summarize* (or selectively quote).  You don't want a link-only answer no matter what the link is; answers should be complete and stand alone.

That the same answer addresses two different questions doesn't necessarily mean that the questions are duplicates.  Questions need to be evaluated based on the *question*, not the *answers*.

Comment: What if the link contains a lot of information you can't summarize effectively?

Comment: What do you do if, instead of another answer, it's a blog post or a journal article?  Do the same thing you would do there.  What I'm saying is that its being *a Stack Exchange answer* isn't special.